# Replace matched regex in file content with variables

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I would like to do the following

1. Search file content with pattern (`^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*`)
2. If found, replace the pattern by a String (in variable)
3. Else, append the String (in variable) at end of file

I got stuck on step 2 and step 2 of the script will replace `services:` in file to `${serviceLoopBack}`. What is the problem to my `sed` command?

Test script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

destfile=config.yml

serviceLoopBack="services:|NL|- name: loopback-service|NL||FS||FS|url: http://127.0.0.1:12345|NL||FS||FS|routes:|NL||FS||FS|- name: loopback-test-route"
serviceLoopBackWithFrontSpace="|NL||NL|$serviceLoopBack"

if grep -E "^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*" $destfile
then
    # service tag found, replace target string
    sed -i -e 's/^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*/${serviceLoopBack}/g' $destfile
else
    # service tag not found, append at end of file
    echo $serviceLoopBackWithFrontSpace >> $destfile
fi

# replace separator 1 to new line
sed  -i -e 's/|NL|/\n/g' $destfile

# replace separator 2 to space
sed  -i -e 's/|FS|/ /g' $destfile
```

Comment: Related: [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Comment: With `grep -E`, `[ \t]` will match the space, the backslash and the letter `t`, which probably isn't what you want. Standard regexes don't support C-style backslash-escapes. (`grep -P` would support them, though, along with the Perl ones.) Use `[[:blank:]]` (space and tab) or `[[:space:]]` (other whitespace characters too) or `$'[ \t]'` (letting the shell turn the `\t` into the literal TAB) instead.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. I am looking for space and tab, not notice `\t` is not supported. `[[:blank:]]` suit for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your second `sed` call, you have enclosed the program in single quotes (`' ... '`). While this is recommended practice, single quotes prevent the shell from expanding shell variables such as `${serviceLoopBack}`, so that text will remain verbatim instead of being replaced by the shell variable's content.

One possibility is to use double-quotes instead of single quotes, as in

```
sed -i -e "s,^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*,${serviceLoopBack}," "$destfile"
```

Alternatively, assemble the `sed` expression in a shell variable using `printf`:

```
printf -v prog 's,^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*,%s,' "$serviceLoopBack"
sed -i -e "$prog" "$destfile"
```

**Note** that I am using `,` as separator instead of `/`, since your replacement text contains `/` also and this would otherwise confuse `sed`. Also, I omitted the `g` option since I assume that there will be only one match per line.

You may want to look at the quoting in your shell script anyway, see [e.g. this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/377345) on the reasons.

However, if `sed` is not a strict requirement, almost the entire shell script can be replaced with an `awk` program instead (which is faster):

```
awk -v slb="services:|NL|- name: loopback-service|NL||FS||FS|url: http://127.0.0.1:12345|NL||FS||FS|routes:|NL||FS||FS|- name: loopback-test-route" \
 '/^[ \t]*services:/{$0=slb;f=1}
  {gsub(/\|NL\|/,"\n"); gsub(/\|FS\|/," ")} 1; END{if (!f) {print "\n\n" slb}}' "$destfile"
```

- This will import the "service loop back" specification in the `awk` variable `slb`.
- It will then check if any line matches the `services:` pattern, and if so, replace the entire line with the string stored in `slb` (which I infer is what you actually want to achieve). At the same time, set a flag `f` to 1.
- Using `gsub()`, replace all occurences of `|NL|` with a new-line, and all occurences of `|FS|` with a space.
- The seemingly "stray" `1` instructs `awk` to print the current line, including all modifications made so far.
- At the end, if `f` is still unset, append the "service loop back" line with the leading pattern (however, already converted to `\n\n`).

Note that `awk` will not edit the file in-place, unless you have an `awk` implementation that understands the `-i inplace` option. You may have to redirect the output to a temporary file and then replace the `$destfile` with the temporary file afterwards.

All in all, however, since you are using a structured language (YAML), it might be worthwile using a dedicated parser such as `yq` instead of line-oriented text processing tools.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your `sed` command is that variables are not expanded inside single quotes, so you need to enclose the sed script in double quotes instead. To illustrate:

```
$ var="foo"
$ echo bar | sed 's/bar/$var/'
$var

$ echo bar | sed "s/bar/$var/"
foo
```

Your next problem will be that your replacement string contains `/` so you need to use a different delimiter. Something like:

```
sed -i -e "s#^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*#${serviceLoopBack}#g" "$destfile"
```

And is there any point to the `g`? Do you expect more than one match per line?

Here's what should be a working version of your script with a few improvements (quoting, using `grep -qm1` to remove output and stop at the first match):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

destfile=config.yml

serviceLoopBack="services:|NL|- name: loopback-service|NL||FS||FS|url: http://127.0.0.1:12345|NL||FS||FS|routes:|NL||FS||FS|- name: loopback-test-route"
serviceLoopBackWithFrontSpace="|NL||NL|$serviceLoopBack"

if grep -Eqm 1 "^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*" "$destfile"
then
    # service tag found, replace target string
    sed -i -e "s#^[ \t]*services:[ \t]*#${serviceLoopBack}#g" "$destfile"
else
    # service tag not found, append at end of file
    printf '%s\n' "$serviceLoopBackWithFrontSpace" >> "$destfile"
fi

# replace separator 1 with newline and separator 2 with space
sed -i -e 's/|NL|/\n/g' -e 's/|FS|/ /g'  "$destfile"
```